# C-SERVER : HTTP response missing new line

Tags: c, bash, shell, webserver

**C-SERVER:**
execute external script : **/script**
response from script stored in "**vvv**" and "**vvv**" is sent to client.

```
fp = popen("/script", "r");
fgets(vvv, 500, fp);

write(client_fd, vvv, sizeof(vvv) - 1);
close(client_fd);
```

contents of **/script**

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -e 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n';
```

test with netcat:

```
echo TEST | nc <ip> <port>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

**problem:** it fails to include a new line so it can work with web browser.

**C-SERVER:**

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <string.h>

char inn[100];

FILE *fp;
char vvv[100];

int main()
{
  int one = 1, client_fd;
  struct sockaddr_in svr_addr, cli_addr;
  socklen_t sin_len = sizeof(cli_addr);

  int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (sock < 0)
    err(1, "can't open socket");

  setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &one, sizeof(int));

  int port = 85;
  svr_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  svr_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  svr_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

  if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &svr_addr, sizeof(svr_addr)) == -1) {
    close(sock);
    err(1, "Can't bind");
  }

  listen(sock, 5);
  while (1) {
    client_fd = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &sin_len);
    size_t bytesRead = read(client_fd,inn,sizeof(inn) - 1);

    fp = popen("/script", "r");
    fgets(vvv, 500, fp);
    printf(vvv);


    write(client_fd, vvv, sizeof(vvv) - 1);
    close(client_fd);
  }
}
```

Comment: I am too new to C. I wouldnt even know how to do something like **vvv = vvv + "/n"** if that is the answer of course.

Comment: well, that wouldn't be

Comment: your buffer `vvv` is 100 bytes yet you're giving limit 500 to `fgets`, why's that?

Comment: if script did **echo 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n';** (no -e flag) still wouldnt work. result is : **HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n**

Comment: @Antti Haapala, I do not even understand those things. just giving extra room to things until I get the script to be functional. those things are secondary worry for future.

Comment: I can not echo 2 lines in the **/script** everything has to be a single line because popen stops reading after first echo.

Comment: perhaps I need to append **\r\n** to the "**vvv**" variable in the C-SERVER itself. the question is HOW ?

Comment: **sprintf(vvv, "%s %s", vvv, "\r\n");** seems to be working but web browser still not happy.

Comment: Include an introductory paragraph explaining what you're trying to do in a high level, and what you're trying. Right now it just reads like a bunch of code. That should follow your introduction, not replace it.

Comment: I actually prefer everything came from the script. because I can not just glue things in the C-SERVER. wouldnt be logical.

Comment: @Brandin, the post includes a portion : " **problem**: it fails to include a new line so it can work with web browser. "

Comment: Forget the **/script**.. I tried to just be direct.. web browser is now trying to simply download.. **sprintf(vvv, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n test");**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware that the HTTP header and content are separated by an empty line. This is also the case, if you don't provide any content at all.

Also `echo` will already append a line break after the line. Use `printf` instead:

```
#!/bin/sh
printf 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n';
printf '\r\n';
printf 'Content'; # provide some content
```

But this requires now that you need to read multiple lines from `fp`. Add an additional loop to read every line from `fp`:

```
...

while (1) {
  client_fd = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &sin_len);
  size_t bytesRead = read(client_fd,inn,sizeof(inn) - 1);

  fp = popen("/script", "r");

  while (!feof(fp)) {
    // be careful here to use `sizeof` instead of the harcoded `500`
    fgets(vvv, sizeof(vvv), fp);
    // only write the number of bytes read
    write(client_fd, vvv, strlen(vvv));
    printf(vvv);
  }

  close(client_fd);
}

...
```

Also consider to use `fread` instead of `fgets` to prevent truncation of long lines.

Answer (score 0):

Again, please read the documentation. [`fgets`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.7.2p2) reads:

> at most one less than the number of characters specified by n from the stream pointed to by stream into the array pointed to by s. **No additional characters are read after a new-line character (which is retained)** or after end-of-file. A null character is written immediately after the last character read into the array.

The HTTP response must contain **2** CRLF newlines - the first terminates the status line and the second separates the status line from the body:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n
\r\n
```

Your script should likewise produce these newlines as such:

```
echo -e 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n';
```

However your `fgets` call stops short - it reads until the first `\n` character only. Actually you shouldn't use `fgets` at all, but instead use `fread` repeatedly until `EOF` is met, something like

```
fp = popen("/script", "r");
while (!feof(fp) && !ferror(fp)) {
    size_t bytes_read = fread(vvv, 1, sizeof(vvv), fp);
    if (read) {
        write(client_fd, vvv, bytes_read);
    }
}
pclose(fp); // must *absolutely* close the pipe with pclose
```

---

(P.S. HTTP/1.1 protocol is a bit more complicated, and if you claim to support it then you need to support all kinds of extra stuff too)